# Are Docker Volumes using local driver shared across Docker Service Replicas?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I was reading the docker documentation about starting a service with volumes. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-service-with-volumes

Say for example I create a Swarm with one manager node and one worker node.

In my docker stack file I specify:

1. Deploy one service with 2 replicas.
2. A volume using local driver for that service. Call it myVolume.
3. Through constraints to only schedule service replicas on that one worker node.

The docs say "When you start a service and define a volume, each service container uses its own local volume. None of the containers can share this data if you use the local volume driver, but some volume drivers do support shared storage."

Are the docs above saying that changes made to myVolume from replica 1 will not be seen in myVolume from replica 2 (and vice versa)? Docker creates a new space under _data for every new replica of a service?

Answer (score 0):

What the docs are pointing out, and probably need some rewording, is that the local volume driver with default options will store data locally to each node. This is attempting to remove confusion from those assuming that volumes in swarm mode somehow replicate their data automatically between nodes, they don't. So a service spread across 4 nodes would have 4 different volumes. What's needed in a multi node swarm cluster is to place persistent data in a globally accessible location to support services migrating between nodes, e.g. nfs, which you can actually implement with the local volume driver.

With a single node swarm cluster, or a service constrained to a single node, the same name volume mount will make the same files available to each replica/container, just as if you ran it without swarm.